# Video Player in Unity 2D playing audio but not showing visual when setting active after being inactive

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I haven't used Unity very much, and I'm trying to make a game where it plays a video in the background, then removes the video, then continues playing the video again (continues following this pattern) to see if the player's score is affected by having the video playing in the background.

I have the video player script on a panel with a raw image, and the current problem is that after the video has played for 15 seconds and then I make the panel inactive, when I make it active again the audio from the video plays, but the video does not appear. Additionally, it always restarts the video each time, but I would like it to continue playing where it left off. I tried using videoPlayer.Pause, but I don't want the video still to be visible in the background.

Any advice would be very helpful!

Here is my videoPlayer script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class streamVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage image;

    //public VideoClip videoToPlay;

    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private VideoScript script;

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
            Application.runInBackground = true;
            StartCoroutine(playVideo());
    }

IEnumerator playVideo()
    {
        videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        if (audioToggle.audioBool)
        {
            audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
            audioSource.Pause();
        }



        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;

        videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
        videoPlayer.url = VideoScript.myPath;
        videoPlayer.isLooping = true;

        //Set Audio Output to AudioSource
        videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;

        //Assign the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played
        videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
        videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);

        //Set video To Play then prepare Audio to prevent Buffering
        //videoPlayer.clip = videoToPlay;
        videoPlayer.Prepare();

        //Wait until video is prepared
        while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        //Assign the Texture from Video to RawImage to be displayed
        image.texture = videoPlayer.texture;


            videoPlayer.Play();


            //if game audio is on
            if (audioToggle.audioBool)
            {
                //Play Sound
                audioSource.Play();
            }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And here is my timer script that sets the videoPanel active:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class timeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject videoPanel;
    public float mediaTime = 0;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        mediaTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (VideoScript.isVideo & mediaTime >= Random.Range(10,20))
//VideoScript.isVideo is just a bool that checks whether a video was loaded by the player
        {
            videoPanel.SetActive(!videoPanel.activeSelf);
            mediaTime = 0;


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pause the video and hide the mesh renderer component.

```
videoPlayer.Pause();
videoPlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
...
videoPlayer.Play();
videoPlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
```